# How to handle errors inside reducers?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I've my loggerService and I need to catch all errors in reducer and send it via my service to the server.

How can I do it? I know that reducer should be a pure function, but still any ideas?

I need to add in reduser try catch

```
    case actions.GAMES_LOADED{
       ......
       try{}
       catch(err){
       this.loggerService.error(err);
    }
}
```

Or maybe throw something in reducer and catch it in some place...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:** You don't.

**Why?** - The reducer is only responsible for updating the store, it should **not** perform any business-logic or validate data - any data that reaches the store should be already valid and just be stored/updated/removed from the store.

**Possible solution:** You should do these kind of operations either in an [**effect**](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/intro.md) or in some **service** that is responsible for fetching/creating the data.

Comment: I dont need to add any business-logic or validate data. i just want to add try catch and if there are any error to log it... just to call logger.service.error(error)

Comment: Then you'll have to do that outside of angular - besides, a reducer should be written in a way that there are no errors - what kind of error are thrown in your reducer?

Comment: For example I got some response from server, and for some reasons in response missing properties on object. While mapping inside reducer error was happened, errors like that I want to handle and send to log.

Comment: Exactly this kind of operation is called _"data validation"_, which should be done directly when the data is received in your data-service - the reason for this is, that if the server send maleformed data, the service should prevent this incorrect/incomplete data from entering the application-lifecycle.

Comment: You should be able to relay error state in store, if only to display a message to the user that the recent  request (+ retries) have failed. All previously displayed data might be invalid at this point and this is a *state* too.

Comment: @user776686 sure you should display issues to the user and update the store accordingly, but you certainly should NOT implement some try/catch for this in your reducer - you reduce should in fact not even care about any of the information it receives, it simply stores the data handed to it (that being said: these are are just guidelines, technically there are no limits)

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that reducer is only responsible for updating the store. It is rather responsible for updating application state..store as well as UI state. So in this case there is a valid responsibility for the reducer to update error state in the application. Upon redirection from effect on error by some error action reducer can update error state. However in that case same reducer should wipe out error state upon receiving any success action. But I am not suggesting that this is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you add to your application state a "loadingMessage" item, you can set that state in this reducer to empty or a message. This can then be read by a component using a store selector and if not empty, logged or a dialog produced or whatever you wish to do with this state.