# Data transformation in Class vs Reducer (ngrx/redux)

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, reducers

Using ngrx/redux, and following the [ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) as close as possible. Now I'm doing this somewhere in the application:

```
get totalItems (): number {
   return sumBy(this._data.items, 'metadata.value');
}
```

Where the `_data` is the raw async data from a remote server, and is part of some data of a `User`.

Now I have some options:

**1. Create a Class `User`**

```
constructor (public _data: UserResponse) {}
```

And have some methods like:

```
get name (): string {
  return this._data.name;
}

get address (): string {
  return this._data.address;
}
```

And additionally things like the aforementioned `totalItems`, and other shortcuts to get a different result than the raw data.
What I don't like is the repetition of the properties, and where to use this class;

- Do I use the `User` Class in the `api-service`, and return the transformed data to the the `@Effect` module, which in turn will trigger the `SUCCESS` or `FAILED` actions?
- Do I put it in the `@Effect` module, right before the action triggers?

  - Do I use `extends` or `implements` on the angular component?

Another thing is that we apply the transformed data on the `payload` property, which would make it hard to debug the raw remote data.

**2. Another option would be to transform this data inside the `reducer`:**

The current reducer:

```
case ActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
   return {
     ...state,
     users: action.payload
   };
```

What I could do:

```
case ActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
   return {
     ...state,
     users: action.payload.map((user) => {
        return({ 
          ...user, 
           totalItems: sumBy(user.items, 'metadata.value' });
     })
   };
```

Is this an anti-pattern or bad practice? Because I see `.filter` being used in examples all the time, and I don't see summing up as being impure, so what would be the arguments for/against doing it in the reducer? This way I could eliminate needing a `User` class, and load all the necessary data into a component.

And, keeping the reducers from filling up with a lot of logic, perhaps make a separate reducer for this, which "listens" to the same actions.

**Option 3:**

Put it in a selector:

```
export const selectUsers = createSelector(selectUsersState, (state: Userstate) => state.payload.map((a: UsersResponse) => new User(a)))
```

Reading this answer by @dan_abramov: [How to put methods onto the objects in Redux state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352982/how-to-put-methods-onto-the-objects-in-redux-state/32922984#32922984) implies me that the 2nd option makes more sense for this, as he states:

> "In Redux, you don't really have custom models. Your state should be
>   plain objects (or Immutable records). They are not expected to have
>   any custom methods."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445082/how-to-handle-errors-inside-reducers/41445361#41445361

Comment: @olsn, can you explain the difference between filtering in a reducer, and summing up a property (still pure?)

Comment: There is no difference - because the point is, that in both cases data-operations are performed where data is being mutated/created/deleted - and the ngrx-pattern states that the reducer should only store the data and not do any transformations - technically you are free to do whatever you want - and I would also advice you to do what's best for your project and not follow any rule blindly - but you were asking for the pattern/anti-pattern, and your way would be an anti-pattern

Comment: Which way? the 1st or 2nd?

Comment: I was referring to the 2nd way, but the first one is as well againt the pattern of a serializable redux-state (as you already saw in the answer of @dan_abramov) - as a personal advice: Option 1 => nogo! __dont__ do it! it will most likely cause trouble sooner or later - Option 2: even though it's against the pattern - you will probably be fine using that solution - if you want to go "by the book" - use `@ngrx/effects` (this will however add quite some complexity and a lot more code to your app)

Comment: @olsn, thanks, I was leaning towards putting it in the `@Effects`, but then I still kind of have problems with having a Class model in the store, which I don't know if that's a good or bad idea...

Comment: Classes in the store are never a good idea ;-) - think of the store of something that should be serializable and deserializable in 1 or 2 lines of code to persist the state or undo and redo things with a minimum amount of code